# How to add support for the JPEG image format

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg

After installing Imagemagick, I've tested it with jpg image, like this:

```
identify 1.jpg
```

But, I got this result:

```
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `1.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.
```

Then, I tried to add support for JPEG format by:

```
yum install libjpeg libjpeg-devel
```

but, I got:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package libjpeg available.
No package libjpeg-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

I thought I need to update the apt-get, I did:

```
apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-devel
```

but, I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-devel
```

Is there an easy way to get those libraries installed ? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Why are you using `yum`?  That is the package manager for a different distribution (Red Hat & Fedora), and if you have used `yum` to install imagemagick, I'm not at all surprised it can't find the libraries!  You should only install software with apt-get unless you *really* know what you're doing!  Also, "Ubuntu 12" isn't specific enough... There are two versions of Ubuntu that start with "12": 12.04 and 12.10.  Ubuntu versions are based on release date:  12.04 was released April (month #04) of '12, and 12.10 was released October of '12.  Please be sure and specify!

Comment: I have Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit, I didn't install imagemagick with yum, instead I 
tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz, cd ImageMagick-6.8.0, cd ImageMagick-6.8.0-4, ./configure, make, sudo make install,   sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib

Comment: try apt-get install libjpeg-dev

Comment: It's a really great answer there
[http://askubuntu.com/a/746195](http://askubuntu.com/a/746195)

Comment: how in the world can any imagemagick package be of ANY use without support for JPEG prepackaged?! That's like selling pizza without cheese or bread or tomato sauce.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing from source the jpeg encoding library available at http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz.

```
cd /usr/local/src
tar xvfz jpeg-8c.tar.gz
cd jpeg-8c
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$CONFIGURE_PREFIX
make
sudo make install
```

Then I re-installed ImageMagick from source:

```
cd /usr/local/src
tar xvfz ImageMagick-6.6.9-5.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.6.9-5
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp
make
sudo make install
```

Now its working, I've tested it like this:

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/project/tmp$ identify 1.jpg
1.jpg JPEG 128x106 128x106+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.22KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/ in .profile

Comment: I only installed the first jpegsrc from source and reinstalled ImageMagick via `apt-get` and it worked too.

Answer (score 6):

If you decide to build ImageMagick from source, you need to be prepared to manually resolve all dependencies. Unless you have a pressing need, you should install all software on Ubuntu from a repository -- either the official repos or a PPA.

If you install Imagemagick using APT (`apt-get`, Synaptic, Software Center, etc.), then JPG files will work just fine, as I confirmed on my machine.

If your reason for building from source is to get a more recent version, hunt for a PPA that tracks the most recent version. If you're building from source in order to help with development, then you should find out from the Imagemagick folks just what is required to succesfully build it from source. It might be that you need to specify some flag to `./configure` or have some development library installed before running `./configure`.

But normally, building from source just needlessly complicates things.

Oh, by the way, Red Hat and Ubuntu use different names for packages. So if `yum` complains about a missing package, it shouldn't be surprising if `apt-get` can't find a package by that name. You shouldn't mix package managers on a system unless you have a really good reason to do so. Even then, try every other option first.

Comment: I have no specific reason to building from source, if installing Imagemagick using APT (apt-get, Synaptic, Software Center, etc.) will fix the JPG files issue, I will go with it, can you please point me how to install Imagemagick using APT like you did ?

Comment: @SamirSabri: Just search the Software Center or Synaptic. Or use tab completion on `apt-get` to discover the command: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`.

Comment: By the way, I strongly suggest that you remove all previous attempts to install imagemagick before you try to install using my method. Otherwise, you might end up with conflicts.

Comment: Although I've removed previous attempts, I get an error when identify jpg image, like this:

sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/project/tmp$ identify 1.jpg
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `1.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `no decode delegate` error can (quite confusingly) result from imagemagick (or some part of it) not finding the file. So before running to reinstall imagemagick, check with `identify -list format` and `convert -list configure` whether the JPEG format is supported, and if it is, the problem will probably be somewhere else.

For example, `convert -resize 50% foo\ bar.jpg` gave me a `no decode delegate for this image format` eror, but `convert -resize 50% 'foo bar.jpg'` worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that the last two examples with file called `foo bar.jpg` (with a space) should behave exactly the same because the backspace or single quotes are handled by the shell instead of `convert`. There must have have been some typo in the first line, maybe NBSP instead of regular space in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed php5-imagick, try also installing the full imagemagick package. This will install all required libraries, such as the jpeg one.

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Then restart your webserver to reload al libraries:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

JPEG decoding should now work without error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

**sudo apt-get install libjpeg62**

if the above command doesn't work, please go through following link.

http://psx-scene.com/forums/f150/help-install-libjpeg-libpng-ubuntu-9-10-livecd-64122/

Let em know, if this was helpful, good luck... :)

Comment: I tried your solution, I got: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg62 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

But, I still get an error when identify jpg image:

sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/project/tmp$ identify 1.jpg identify: no decode delegate for this image format `1.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.

Comment: okay, I found this : http://blog.ericlamb.net/2008/11/fix-for-convert-no-decode-delegate-for-this-image-format/ please, check and let me know, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've just fixed it before reading your last comment, thanks, I have it in my answer below

Comment: sounds great !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

| **Easiest way** | 
Download "**Synaptic Package Manager**" from Software center. --> removed older libjpeg packages* --> reinstalled libjpeg8 & libjpeg-turbo8 & libjpeg-turbo8-dev.

PS:
I was getting same error. It took me 2 days to get solved. My error when I was trying to display jpg image:

```
no decode delegate for this image format `jpeg' @ error/constitute.c/readimage/504
```

Then, I download "**Synaptic Package Manager**" from Software center. --> removed older libjpeg packages* --> reinstalled libjpeg8 & libjpeg-turbo8 & libjpeg-turbo8-dev.

(*synaptics package manager will show dependency with other package, remove only older independent libjpeg packages)

After that I am able to open JPEG images without any fear of error.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

That error message also appears if you have SPACES in file's names, as imagick and its toolset can't process those correctly on Linux.
So before processing the files with imagemagick, mogrify, or identify, or any of the tools that come with imagemagick, do a

```
sudo find ./ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename -v 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

to replace all spaces in file names with underscores;

I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by installing ImageMagick rpm using dnf command. See my answer here for reference - [ImageMagick PNG delegate install problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745660/imagemagick-png-delegate-install-problems/1346178#1346178)