# ImageMagick PNG delegate install problems

Tags: imagemagick, png

Ubuntu 14.04:

I've downloaded the latest imagemagick source and installed, using option below to configure:

```
root@usve59445:~/im/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7# ./configure --enable-shared --with-png=yes
```

After installation however, I have zero items in my built-in list of delegates:

```
root@usve59445:~/im/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7# identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-03-14
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC License:  
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in):
```

Issue I am getting is 'no delegate for format PNG found' when doing a `convert` command.

I installed the libpng delegate from:  http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/

Extracted the libpng1621.tar.gz into its own folder, then:
Ran configure, make, make install (no error messages)

Now when I try and recompile imagemagick, it still says ' Checking for PNG ... no' and --with-png value has 'no' (even though I configure it with --with-png=yes ).

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Trying to recompile IM using:

root@usve59445:~/im/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7# ./configure --enable-shared=yes --with-png=yes LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib' LIBS=-lpng16

(I *think* I am using the correct LDFLAGS, but not sure)

```
root@usve59445:~/im/libpng-1.6.21# libpng16-config --L_opts
-L/usr/local/lib 

root@usve59445:~/im/libpng-1.6.21# libpng16-config --libs
-lpng16


root@usve59445:~/im/libpng-1.6.21# locate libpng
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.46.0
/usr/bin/libpng-config
/usr/bin/libpng12-config
/usr/include/libpng
/usr/include/libpng12
/usr/include/libpng12/png.h
/usr/include/libpng12/pngconf.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libpng.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libpng12.pc
/usr/local/bin/libpng-config
/usr/local/bin/libpng16-config
/usr/local/include/libpng16
/usr/local/include/libpng16/png.h
/usr/local/include/libpng16/pngconf.h
/usr/local/include/libpng16/pnglibconf.h
/usr/local/lib/libpng.a
/usr/local/lib/libpng.la
/usr/local/lib/libpng.so
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.a
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.la
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16.21.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng16.pc
/usr/local/share/man/man3/libpng.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev
/usr/share/doc/libpng3
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/ANNOUNCE
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/KNOWNBUG
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/libpng-1.2.46.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/examples
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/examples/example.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/examples/pngtest.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-dev/examples/pngtest.png
/usr/share/doc-base/libpng12
/usr/share/man/man1/libpng-config.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/libpng12-config.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libpng.3.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.46-3ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-dev_1.2.46-3ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng3_1.2.46-3ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng3:amd64.list
```

Comment: Installed libpng via this also: apt-get install libpng12-0 - Still getting same checking PNG  ... no  (no delegate found). Installed libjpeg62 via apt-get, did a recompile of IM and it appears successfully in the delegates list - just PNG does not work!!

Comment: You have to install the `-dev` packages (`libpng12-dev`, perhaps), for building software with a library.

Comment: Hi muru, thanks already did that, not working. Trying to use the --x-libraries option like this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237800/configuring-png-on-imagemagick-on-a-linux-server

But 'locate libpng' gives me a lot of different locations (added to question above), not sure which one I should use? (have tried a few, none of which seem to get PNG compiled into IM).

Comment: Spent many hours on this now with no luck. Willing to send a paypal of $50 for anyone with a (working) advice

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are making things a little too hard for yourself, here is a quick and dirty guide that ran well for me on Trusty Tahr:

First pick up a few known dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall \
             libx11-dev libxext-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev \
             libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev
```

This does not quite catch everything so activate the Source repositories by clicking on 'Souce Code' here:

```
Dash >> Software & Updates >> Source Code
```

and then running the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
```

Create a build folder and change to it:

```
mkdir $HOME/imagemagick_build && cd $HOME/imagemagick_build
```

And finally download, extract, compile and install by simply copying and pasting the *entire* code box below into a Terminal window:

```
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-7.0.8-28.tar.bz2 && \
tar xvf ImageMagick-7.0.8-28.tar.bz2 && cd ImageMagick-7.0.8-28 && ./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/imagemagick_build" \
     --pkgname imagemagick --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
     --pkgversion "7.0.8-28" && \
make distclean && sudo ldconfig
```

And finally test this, looking especially for the png you are missing in your own install:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-10 Q16 x86_64 2017-06-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
andrew@corinth:~$
```

And there is the png option you were missing :).

Comment: This works, thanks so much andrew.46!!!! What is your paypal email? (can send via private IM if possible)

Comment: Great to hear that it all works! I do not want money, I prefer to do this as an Open Source thing but thanks for the thought :).

Comment: after hours of other "answers" this one finally worked for me. I think the critical part for me was the known dependencies and `sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick`. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottJungwirth Great news! I have not tested thins answer for a while but I see a small stream of editors have been bumping the version :)

Comment: Thanks -- this mostly worked. Still some errors reported on Linux Mint 32-bit. So I performed the && chained commands on single lines. It seems insane to me how difficult it was/is to get imagemagick in a state where it can do a bit of useful work...

Comment: This solution on 18.04 now only helps with a few things. Which is still significant, because i too have been struggling with this all day. The package is now 7.0.7-37, and the code was adjusted accordingly. Checkinstall now fails. The Delegates list for me after doing this reads - mpeg freetype jng jpeg png ps xml zlib. The thing i really need is missing - tif. Just an update.

Comment: @kimholder I am wary of adjusting this answer for 18.04 as the original question dealth with 14.04 = a long time ago!

Comment: Sure, that's fair enough. I am focussing now on trying to install the delegate packages offered by ImageMagick. I am looking at the currently empty folder usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.7/config-Q16HDRI and wondering if they should be installed there.

Comment: You maybe would have input on my related question, https://askubuntu.com/q/1042436/364597

Comment: Is there anyway to uninstall the insane amount of packages that 'build-dep' installed once you compiled imagemagick? Do I just need the binaries for it to work?

Comment: @Michael Probably best not to try and weed out too much as for sure there will be some breakage :(. However if you are keen have a look at `ldd` for the various executables that come with imagemagick. Sounds like too much hard work to me though....

Comment: @andrew.46 - Thanks and I agree. Also, I'm worried about security issues with so many packages being installed. I'm looking into dropping ImageMagick, maybe ubuntu has a safer more compatible library for 14.04, or maybe just resizing png's in php itself.

Comment: As an outsider and primarily a Windows user, this seems exceedingly overcomplicated. Why does IM not simply handle this stuff on its own? Why do I have to go to such great lengths just to get basic PNG support? Sigh. This is why I don't use Linux except for dev work...

Answer (score 1):

I installed ImageMagick7.0.11 as well as ImageMagick7.1.0 by extracting it's tar.gz files.  But it did not work. Finally I had to install it using the rpm only. The 'dnf' command does the trick for you. If apt-get is not working, then 'dnf' might be the right solution for your RHEL/CentOS 8. Check this link for reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555466/how-to-install-apt-get-and-dpkg

Now, when I hit the magick -version or convert -

version command, I can see this output which is correct: Version:

> ImageMagick 7.0.11-13 Q16 x86_64 2021-05-17 https://imagemagick.org
> Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
> https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
> Modules OpenMP(4.5) Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fontconfig
> freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps
> raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib

Initially, for me too, this 'Delegates(build-in)' section was coming blank, when I kept trying hard using yum command.

Comment: Note that mixing and matching package managers (`dpkg`/`apt` _versus_ `dnf`/`yum` in your proposed case) is rarely a good idea, because, although installed packages _might_ work, they can have dependencies — and each system will handle them differently (and not know about the other system's dependencies). At best, you get a few broken packages here and there while 'trying hard using yum'; at worst, you might actually replace mission-critical components (such as `libc`) which can totally brick your system. Tread carefully! Installing from `.deb` packages is **always** a better idea...

Answer (score 1):

andrew.46's answer provides solution for building correctly on any debian-like distro, but does not really answer why the original poster's build was not finding libpng.

Easy way to find the culprit is to run `pkg-config --cflags libpng` as follows

```
user@mac ~ % pkg-config --cflags libpng
Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'zlib', required by 'libpng', not found
```

This provides insight into what's missing. In my case it was zlib. After installing zlib:

```
user@mac ~ % pkg-config --cflags libpng
-I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include
```