# How to install the latest version of ImageMagick?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I am trying to install the latest version of ImageMagick.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. After I apt-get update, the version of ImageMagick it lists is 6.7.7.10

However, I want to use ImageMagick version 6.8.9.9. Is there a way to install this version with apt-get or some package manager without upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Perhaps this post might be useful to you: http://askubuntu.com/a/746195/57576

Comment: before installing the latest, better check if it work or not. you can download the complete executable from https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick, chmod +x and run it. In my case, it is still unable to identify specific dds files, so there is no point on installing the latest.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29006#p129405, there is a PPA that provides the 6.8.9.9 version of ImageMagick for Ubuntu 14.04 at https://launchpad.net/~isage-dna/+archive/ubuntu/imagick that you can try at your own risk:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:isage-dna/imagick
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

### Compile from source.

1. First off, check the current version of imagemagick:

   ```
   $ identify -version
   Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
   Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
   ```

   If it is already installed via apt-get and the version is old, remove it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
   ```
2. Create a `src` directory:

   ```
   mkdir ~/src
   cd ~/src
   ```
3. Download version 6.9.10-23 of Imagemagick source:

   ```
   wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.10-23.tar.gz
   ```
4. Install some packages from apt-get that are necessary for compiling from source:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
   ```
5. Untar source and cd into directory:

   ```
   tar xf ImageMagick-6.9.10-23.tar.gz
   cd ImageMagick-6.9.10-23/
   ```
6. Configure, make and checkinstall:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   checkinstall
   ```
7. Update links/bindings:

   ```
   ldconfig
   ```
8. Verify and:

   ```
   $ identify -version
   Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 2019-01-02 https://imagemagick.org
   Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
   Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP
   Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr 
   lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib
   ```
9. Party!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Used on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: any idea how to also change the imagick version that PHP is using ? i originally had 6.9.7 and upgraded to imagick 7 and while the links point to the new one, php is still using the old one

Answer (score 1):

Download and install latest `ImageMagick` version on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

```r
:~$ wget https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
:~$ tar -xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
:~$ sudo rm -rf ImageMagick.tar.gz
:~$ ls -d */ | grep '^ImageMagick*'
ImageMagick-7.0.11-14/
:~$ ## and then cd the directory
:~$ cd ImageMagick-7.0.11-14/
```

For basic user

```r
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ ./configure
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo make
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo make install
```

For advanced user

```r
:~$ ## for advanced user
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ ./configure --with-modules
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo make
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo make install
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ /usr/local/bin/convert logo: logo.gif
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ sudo make check
:~/ImageMagick-7.0.11-14$ cd ~
:~$ sudo rm -rf ImageMagick-7.0.11-14
```

```r
:~$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-13 Q32 x86_64 2021-05-16 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zip zlib
```

source : https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#linux

source : [`zulhfreelancer/image-magick.md`](https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/e104e4b330c8dbc6622d92b8cd525bf6)

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to install from package manager. The newest release is packaged in appimage. You can direct use the downloaded file as standalone executable in any distro.

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/releases

```
# to see full options of appimage, such as mount it and check the internal files.
./ImageMagick--clang-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-help

# to use it just treat ./ImageMagick--clang-x86_64.AppImage as magick

./ImageMagick--clang-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-help

./ImageMagick--clang-x86_64.AppImage identify -verbose 2-layer.xcf
```