# How to upgrade imagemagic on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, imagemagick

Currently, ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I attempt to upgrade it to ImageMagick-7.0.6-5  follow below steps:

```
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && apt-get build-dep imagemagick -y
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xzvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
ls
cd  ImageMagick-7.0.6-5/
./configure
make clean
make
checkinstall
ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

But it doesn't work, the installed Image Magick is still ImageMagick 6.7.7-10:

```
# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

The output of `type -a convert`:

```
convert is /usr/bin/convert
```

Please help me to upgrade ImageMagic!

Comment: Add the output of `type -a convert`, please.

Comment: convert is /usr/bin/convert

Comment: Can't see what you have missed but perhaps a version number issue? This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/746195/57576