# What is simplest process to get ImageMagick 7 with PNG support on Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, imagemagick, png, libpng

I've tried to find a simple explanation for several hours but I just can't seem to find anything useful. I'm primarily a Windows programmer with some experience with Linux-based OSes. For some reason doing `apt install imagemagick` only gives me a really old version (pre-2012) and there's a change in the later versions that I need, which means I need to build from source.

Compiling IM 7 on Ubuntu 18.04 is simple enough: Download tar.gz, extract, `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. However it seems that PNG support is not included by default (why??).

I've tried doing `./configure --with-png` but that didn't achieve anything (I see `--with-png=yes no`, which presumably means "yes, you've asked for PNG support but no, I haven't given it to you"). I've seen many forum posts and SE questions about this, but everyone asking seems to have some prior knowledge which I am clearly missing and the questions appear to be about some later step in the process.

So, **what do I actually need to do to get PNG support?**

(And as some bonus questions: Why is there no documentation for this? Why does it not include PNG support out of the box? Why are there no prebuilt binaries for Ubuntu?)

Related question: [Imagemagick still exists after apt remove?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1216476/338364)

Comment: Have you installed libpng and libpng-devel with apt? The png support is enabled by default in 7.x and should work.

Comment: Try to install it using apt first. It should install dependencies. Then remove imagemagick without removing its dependencies and try again your manual compilation.

Comment: @Gryu How do I remove imagemagick without removing its dependencies?

Comment: `sudo apt remove imagemagick` removes only imagemagick. What is your imagemagick version from repositories?

Comment: @Gryu If you mean the version I get with `apt install`, it said `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114`. Though since building from source I seem to only get the new (PNG-less) version when I run (for example) `magick -version`

Comment: @Clonkex I have not experimented with this but perhaps a small variation of this question and answer might do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/q/745660/57576

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend ImageMagick Easy Install (IMEI):

https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei/

It tracks down all the source/development libraries needed for the additional ImageMagick "delegates" (image formats in IM-speak). Plus, it can also incrementally update your local install from newer source after the initial installation.

Installation steps as of now:

```
git clone https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei
cd imei
sudo ./imei.sh
```

Comment: You should at least provide som installation details from that link.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**ImageMagick** doesn't find `libpng` on its own. The simplest way to tell it how to find, compile and link with `libpng` is by installing  `libpng` followed by `pkg-config`:

```
sudo apt install build-essential libpng-dev pkg-config
```

Now you can see if it works:

```
./configure | grep -i png

checking for libpng >= 1.0.0... yes
  PNG               --with-png=yes      yes
  CFLAGS          = -I/usr/include/libpng16  -fopenmp -Wall -g -O2 -mtune=amdfam10 -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  LIBS            =           -lpng16 -lz                         -lz     -lm    -lpthread 
  DELEGATES       = png zlib
```

Comment: _"New contributor"_ with 166k on SO lol. Cheers for the answer; if I have to build IM again at some point I'll try this method :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error message you were getting, but I was getting `` convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562 `` when working with jpegs with a fresh ImageMagick install from source.

To resolve it:

1. uncomment `deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted` in /etc/apt/sources.list
2. install dependencies

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt build-dep imagemagick
```

3. Reinstall ImageMagick

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

source: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-imagemagick-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux