# Problem installing ImageMagick 7 using IMEI

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, imagemagick, github, signature

I tried to install ImageMagick 7 by IMEI from github:

https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei/

but always had this answer:

```
   Signature verification failed!

 Please check /var/log/imei.log for details.
```

and in imei.log:

```
./imei.sh: line 283: : No such file or directory
./imei.sh: line 286: : No such file or directory
Can't open  for reading, No such file or directory
140131941683840:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('','r')
140131941683840:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load key file
```

My current version is 6.9.10-23, but it seems not working correct with jp2 encoding (don't create a jp2, but a tiff called jp2).
I have version 7.1.0-2 on win10 and it works fine!
So I want to install latest version of this software, and as I read in some discussion, I try to install by IMEI.

How can I have IM7?

mg

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Which steps you did?

Comment: The current version of `ImageMagick` is 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4 and is available from the ubuntu software center. If you need v7, please explain your reason in your question by using [edit]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 virtualized on WSL on win10. <br/>I followed the steps you can read as answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216469/what-is-simplest-process-to-get-imagemagick-7-with-png-support-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Looks like you have had installed version 6.5.2 of IMEI, which was released one day before you've posted this question: https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei/commit/a55692c3582c816b1f3ab8eb8628abfa0e71d26d#diff-49155aca3829a4bb7ba8eb07d3f0b772dc7dad1fe7e04f0db1d1f8dc9485c0c1

So upgrading to the latest version of IMEI will most likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have corrupted download. The application requires `bash`, `openssl` and `wget`, so you need to install them first by

```
sudo apt-get install bash openssl wget
```

Then download again by following [official guide](https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei/#verify-installer-integrity):

```
cd /tmp

wget https://dist.1-2.dev/imei.sh && \                                  # Download IMEI
wget https://dist.1-2.dev/imei.sh.sig && \                              # Download signature file
wget https://dist.1-2.dev/imei.sh.pem && \                              # Download public key
openssl dgst -sha512 -verify imei.sh.pem -signature imei.sh.sig imei.sh # Verify
```

and then run the installer

```
sudo bash ./imei.sh
```

Comment: Wow! It works fine! My PC has compiled and installed IM7 in 42 minutes (is it normal???), but I just tried the conversion in jp2 and all goes right. This solution is the right one!!!!! thx!

Comment: @Gazzubuteo I can't speak to the compile time personally, but I would ask if the files are on the Windows drive (e.g. `/mnt/c`) or the root filesystem (e.g. `/home/...`).  If you are using WSL2, there can be a *huge* slowdown when using Windows drives, especially when there are many small files (as I imagine the source that you are working with might have).

Comment: IMEI installs everything it needs by itself (e.g. openssl). It also doesn't rely on wget, it alternatively works with cURL or httpie.