# Delete link to command to retry ImageMagick installation

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, imagemagick

TLDR: I messed up an installation of Imagemagick and I am trying to reset back so that when I type magick it simply says `Command 'magick' not found...` rather than `bash: /usr/local/bin/magick: No such file or directory` so that I can fresh install it with `sudo apt`

Full story:

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and in the process, it seems to have removed ImageMagick, so I followed the instructions [here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/) to re-install it. All went fine until I got the problems also explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format). None of this worked and so I went into my `usr/local/lib` and just deleted everything imageMagick related (in hindsight probably not smart but I thought since I installed it from source I could just do this).

I then tried repeating the process again and it seemed to get me back to a point where magick would work but still with the same delegate problem, this time round I removed it using `sudo make uninstall` after realising it was available on a `sudo apt install` (I must have just typed it wrong when I first tried).

However at this point no matter what I do when I try and call `magick` I just get `bash: /usr/local/bin/magick: No such file or directory`

Can someone help explain where I am going wrong and if there is a way to completely undo all this?

For reference when I run `sudo apt list imagemagick -a` this is what I get:

```
imagemagick/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick/focal 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 amd64

imagemagick/focal-updates,focal-security 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 i386
imagemagick/focal 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 i386
```

I'm not very good with complex command line stuff but to me this looks like it is somehow installed?

Comment: It sounds like your shell may have hashed the path - what is the output of `type -a magick`?

Comment: ... see also [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found)

Comment: I have used ```hash -r``` and that has resolved that bit of the problem, but when I tried re-installing imagemagick again, the ```magick``` command doesn't work but ```identify``` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the problem after using `hash -r` as suggested in the comments. I also discovered there were other imagemagick packages installed which I needed to remove before installing everything else again.